# how can I install web.py in windows7?

Tags: python, web.py

I downloaded web.py from this address:http://webpy.org/static/web.py-0.37.tar.gz
and then extracted and copied the file to  python address in my pc and ran setup.py. But still when I write "import web" in python(2.7), I get this error "No module named web". How can I install web.py correctly?
I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Why don't you just use `pip install web.py`?

Comment: I really don't know what is that. I'm being happy if you explain a little and say how install it.thank you.

Comment: did you run `python setup.py install` from the command line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: no,how can run from command line? I just double click setup.py.

Answer (score 0):

```
easy_install web.py
```

or

```
pip install web.py
```

or download *.tar.gz, unpack, and run command from the directory:

```
python.exe setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

any time you cannot find a module in Python, you should start by checking the path Python searches for modules, i.e.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print "\n".join(sys.path)

/usr/bin
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol
```